# Правильная запись переменных

Tags: python, переменные, вывод

```
def create_phone_number(n):
    a = str(n[0])+str(n[1])+str(n[2])
    b = str(n[3])+str(n[4])+str(n[5])
    c = str(n[6])+str(n[7])+str(n[8])+str(n[9])
    
    a1 = print(f'({a}) {b}-{c}')
    return a1
```

Мне необходимо преобразовать массив в номер телефона, с этой задачи я почти справился, но мне нужно чтоб он выводилось в таком формате[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разве `print` возвращает какое-то значение?

Comment: нет, я просто показывают что у меня получается

Comment: Вы присваиваете переменной 'a1' результат, который возвращается из `print` -- это будет `None`.

Comment: Просто верните результат, без его печати внутри функции: `return f'({a}) {b}-{c}'`

Comment: проблема заключается в том что я должен вернуть '(123) 456-7890' а у меня это не получается и я только могу вывести 123 456 7890

Comment: проблема заключается в том, что ты плохо понимаешь что происходит в этом коде. Все у тебя на самом деле получилось, просто ты делаешь не то. Если ты должен вернуть '(123) 456-7890', то и возвращай именно это, а не результат print. Написали уже в комменатрии выше. Ну и заголовок к сути вопроса вообще никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Благодарен я понял свою ошибку

Comment: я думал что если я не буду использовать print я не смогу вывести результат в нужном мне формате

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а такие варианты не подойдут?

```
n = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)
print(f"({n[0]}{n[1]}{n[2]}) {n[3]}{n[4]}{n[5]}-{n[6]}{n[7]}{n[8]}{n[9]}")
print("({}{}{}) {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}".format(*n))
```

или если надо записать в строку, тогда:

```
t1 = f"({n[0]}{n[1]}{n[2]}) {n[3]}{n[4]}{n[5]}-{n[6]}{n[7]}{n[8]}{n[9]}"
t2 = "({}{}{}) {}{}{}-{}{}{}{}".format(*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я увидел скриншот ниже под кодом и понял, что вы решаете задачу на codewars, все задачи которые там решаются не требуют log-выводов всё, что нужно это вернуть значение командой return, вы же в свою очередь возвращаете от функции функцию print, так ни то, что там нельзя, но и вовсе вот решение для вашей задачи (прошу прощение за ошибки):

```
def create_phone_number(n):
    number = f'({n[0]}{n[1]}{n[2]}) {n[3]}{n[4]}{n[5]}-{n[6]}{n[7]}{n[8]}{n[9]}'
    return number
```